# Does P(A|B) = P(A) imply P(B|A) = P(B)?

Tags: probability

If P(A|B) = P(A), does that necessarily mean that P(B|A) = P(B)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's suppose $P(A),P(B) \neq 0$.

Then, $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

But $P(B|A)=\dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}=\dfrac{(P(A |B))P(B)}{P(A)}=P(B)$ as $P(A|B)=P(A)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to probability theory. I understand the meaning of what you've written, but I don't understand how it answers the question. Would you mind explaining a little more, please? Thanks!

Comment: He's using the definition of of conditional probability to describe $P(B|A)$.  But you are given information in the beginning of the problem, particularly that $P(A|B)=P(A)$.  After manipulation, you get that $P(B|A)=P(B)$.  This means it is necessarily true.  Otherwise you would reach some other conclusion, or there would be restrictions on the implications, which there are none.

Comment: I think I get it, but I'm not sure. In the final line, you're saying if we take it that P(A|B) = P(A), then we can substitute in P(A|B) for P(A). So we can expand P(AnB) to (P(A|B))P(B), and then we can multiply through by P(A) or P(A|B) as they're the same, and that leaves us with P(B|A) = P(B). Do I have that right?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven - great - thanks. I think that's the conclusion I was struggling towards :-)

Comment: Yes.  Knowing they are equal allows for substitution and ultimately cancellation leaving $P(B)$.  Thus $P(B|A)=P(B)$ if $P(A|B)=P(A)$.  We can NOT make this true without $P(A|B)=P(A)$ (try it for your self and see what happens....) .

Answer (score 0):

In general:$$P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$$

So if $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ then $P(A)P(B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$.

Draw your conclusion.